# How to partially compare two maps?

Tags: elixir

I'd like to compare two maps for partial equality, i.e. only for certain keys. For example I have the two maps:

```elixir
map1 = %{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
map2 = %{a: 1, c: 3, d: 4}
```

I'm only interested in comparing the two maps for keys :a and :c, so the above example should return true.

I'm looking for a short a general solution as I have a lot of keys in my maps.

Comment: Do you want the solution to return `true` if the maps have any keys in common? Or if they have any key-value pair in common?

Comment: The function should return true if the key/value pairs in scope are the same for both maps, i.e. ignoring all other key/value pairs.

Answer (score 3):

If the set of keys is known in advance, a general and simple solution could be to use [`Enum.all?/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#all?/2) to check a condition for all keys:

```
map1 = %{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}   
map2 = %{a: 1, c: 3, d: 4}
keys = [:a, :c]

Enum.all?(keys, fn key -> map1[key] == map2[key] end) # true
```

Edit: If you need to detect the overlapping keys dynamically, you could do something like

```
def partial_equal?(map1, map2) when is_map(map1) and is_map(map2) do
  Enum.all?(map1, fn {key, value} ->
    case map2 do
      %{^key => another_value} when another_value != value -> false
      _ -> true
    end
  end)
end

# or, more compact
Enum.all?(map1, fn {key, value} -> not match?(%{^key => v} when v != value, map2) end)
```

It will check all key-values from `map1` and will bail with `false` as soon as it finds a key with a different value in `map2`.

```
partial_equal?(%{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3},  %{a: 1, c: 3, d: 4})  # true
partial_equal?(%{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3},  %{a: 1, c: 0})  # false
```

Comment: `map[key]` goes through `Access` and hence [through `:maps.find/2`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.13.2/lib/elixir/lib/map.ex#L256) unlike `Map.get/2` which uses [pattern matching](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.13.2/lib/elixir/lib/map.ex#L455) which is supposedly faster. Anyway, I find my solution using `Map.take/2` to be more straightforward :)

Comment: I agree that `Map.get` is more efficient, I hesitated but I optimized for readability.
Regarding performance, my solutions is highly optimal compared to `Map.take` since it is read only and doesn't rely on building a new map.
A [quick benchmark](https://github.com/sabiwara/enumancer/blob/52da00e0dddaf529e6a4501de60ae1b98f1303a3/bench/partial_map_compare.exs) indicates a [huge gap](https://github.com/sabiwara/enumancer/blob/52da00e0dddaf529e6a4501de60ae1b98f1303a3/bench/partial_map_compare.results.txt) both in speed and especially memory usage.
The impact of Access is small in comparison :)

Comment: Regarding straightforwardness, I like the `Map.take/2` version too, but I believe `Enum.all?` is pretty clear about the intent as well and reads quite naturally.

Comment: Yes, I fully agree.

Answer (score 3):

I’d go with [`Map.take/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#take/2), which would be more idiomatic and clarify the intent better.

```elixir
map1 = %{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
map2 = %{a: 1, c: 3, d: 4}

[map1, map2]
|> Enum.map(&Map.take(&1, [:a, :c]))
|> Enum.reduce(&Kernel.==/2)
#⇒ true
```

For huge maps, though, the @sabiwara’s solution works much better, see comments there.

Comment: I also thought of this but I did `Map.take(map1, keys) == Map.take(map2, keys)`. However, I didn't post it as an answer because this version will produce a copy of both sub-maps, which could be a drawback if there are many `keys`. Sabiwara's version doesn't copy anything and does it in one iteration.

Comment: Indeed, and even huge maps are mentioned in the question. I’ll put a warning there.

Answer (score 0):

I think this function does what you need.

```elixir
@doc """
Returns a boolean indicating if the given maps
have any key-value pairs in common.
"""
@spec have_any_key_value_pair_in_common?(map(), map()) :: boolean()
def have_any_key_value_pair_in_common?(map1, map2) do
  map_set1 = MapSet.new(map1)
  map_set2 = MapSet.new(map2)

  map_set1
  |> MapSet.intersection(map_set2)
  |> Enum.any?() 
end
```

What I'm doing here is converting the maps to "MapSets", which are like mathematical sets (every element is unique). When you do this, each "element" from a map is a key-value pair, e.g. `{:a, 1}`.

Then I get the "intersection" of the two MapSets. This will give me a list of all common elements, i.e. all key-value pairs common to both maps.

With this list, I just have to `Enum.any?` to get a boolean (true if list is not empty, false if empty).

Comment: This will not return `false` when they do have a common key with a different value, so having key-value pairs in common feels a bit different from a partial comparison:

`have_any_key_value_pair_in_common?(%{a: 1, b: 2}, %{a: 1, b: 3}) == true`.

Maybe we should just take the intersection between the map keys and then compare these?

Comment: @sabiwara It will not always return `false` when they "have a common key with a different value". In the example you gave, they have `{:a, 1}` in common so it returns true.
Anyway, i think I didn't understand what you exactly needed.